# Logic for detecting swipe direction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Basically what I am trying to do is create some code that will register when a touch has swiped across the screen, so I can move my character by touch controls.

What I have written only seems to work sometimes, and when it does it makes the character move multiple times.

Here is my code :

```
if (Input.touches [0].phase == TouchPhase.Ended) {

        Debug.Log (Input.touches [0].deltaPosition);
        if (Input.touches[0].deltaPosition.y > Input.touches[0].deltaPosition.x || Input.touches[0].deltaPosition.y > (-Input.touches[0].deltaPosition.x))
            movePlayer ("Up");

        if ((-Input.touches[0].deltaPosition.y) > Input.touches[0].deltaPosition.x || (-Input.touches[0].deltaPosition.y) > (-Input.touches[0].deltaPosition.x))
            movePlayer ("Down");

        if ((-Input.touches[0].deltaPosition.x) > Input.touches[0].deltaPosition.y || (-Input.touches[0].deltaPosition.x) > (-Input.touches[0].deltaPosition.y))
            movePlayer ("Left");

        if (Input.touches[0].deltaPosition.x > Input.touches[0].deltaPosition.y || Input.touches[0].deltaPosition.x > (-Input.touches[0].deltaPosition.y))
            movePlayer ("Right");

    }
```

Any advice would be really helpful

Comment: The up case... `y>x && y>-x`? In words, what are you testing here?

Comment: OK that was from me messing about because I was getting annoyed, but changing it to || instead of && doesn't seem to do anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you've made a decision, you don't need to run anymore tests, so this would be an ideal time for using `else if` and `else`

```
if()
{
}
else if()
{
}
else
{
}
```

to ensure that only a single case could execute.

However... I think your testing is flawed. Wouldn't the following be more appropriate?

```
var dp = Input.touches[0].deltaPosition;
if(Math.Abs(dp.x) > Math.Abs(dp.y))
{
    //gesture had more horizonal movement
    if(dp.x < 0)
    {
        //left
    }
    else
    {
        //right
    }
}
else
{
    //gesture had more vertical movement
    if(dp.y < 0)
    {
        //up
    }
    else
    {
        //down
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks that looks a lot better than mine.  This might sound stupid but what does Math.Abs do?  Does it just make it positive?

Comment: @Zoomz09 Yes, it removes the minus of a negative number, so we're testing which dimension has more "size" irrespective of whether it's positive or negative.

Comment: That'll be handy to know as it makes something like this a lot easier.  Anyway thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [this](http://gamedevelopertips.com/how-detect-swipe-direction-unity/) simple tutorial wich is basically 7 lines of code and works like a charm. Easy and simple. 
You just have to use te build in Unity event system instead to write long and useless code.
**No need to use an update or fixed update.**